# Generate Signed Apk Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageArmeabi-v7aRelease'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build, android-install-apk

Facing mention error when trying to generate signed apk file with my old keys myproject.jks in Android Studio 2.3.

In older version of Android Studio 1.5 same keys are perfectly file and facing no issues in siging and generating apk file for release.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageArmeabi-v7aRelease'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key my_old_key from store "/Users/Android/keystone/xyz.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Comment: your old password and new password are mismatch..
which means you have to give the same password previously used..

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue when update my android studio to 2.3 the latest version

but it's not a issue because i entered the Wrong password the best way is to

create new Key it's not important too much !

it's possible because of your gradle version

see android developer for gradle version

[Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html)

or try this

```
Invalidate Caches/Restart.
```

hope it help